# Regex pattern with dot and quotation mark

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can I declare regex pattern in c#. Pattern starts with quotation mark and later is url address, some thing like below

```
\"www\.mypage\.pl  //<- this is my pattern

string pattern = ? //todo: what should I put there
```

Comment: Are you asking how to put `\"www\.mypage\.pl` into a string, or how to use the RegEx objects themselves?

Comment: I have ready pattern, but I don't know how use it in code. What should I write in pattern declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using verbatim strings:

```
string pattern = @"""www\.mypage\.pl";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\` backslash to escape the regex semantic and revert to the actual literal. If you want to escape

```
"www.mypage.pl
```

you can use

```
\"[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.[0-9a-zA-Z]*
^ this is not to escape the regex but the eventual string
  if you use single quotes you don't need to escape the quotes!
```

Note that `[0-9a-zA-Z]*` will require some more characters like `%` and `-` and `_` to capture all cases according to an *RFC* about URL syntax I can't produce now (it's easy to find online).

If you want to escape

```
\"www\.mypage\.pl
```

you have to escape the escapes as well:

```
\\\"[0-9a-zA-Z]*\\\.[0-9a-zA-Z]*\\\.[0-9a-zA-Z]*
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have already handled (very nicely) how to put the phrase itself into a string.

To use it, you need to refer to the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace, documentation for which is [over at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.aspx). As a (very) quick example:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(content,
                                        regexPattern, newMatchContent);
```

will replace matches for the regular expression `regexPattern` in `content` with `newMatchContent`, and return the result.